# US dead keys Xubuntu not present

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I read some topics about missing the US dead keys missing and can´t find a solution. I did a clean Xubuntu 22.04.3 installation and marked Dutch as system language and US with dead keys for keyboard layout. After installation all works fine but not the dead keys, they are not working and in the language settings the are not present. Is there a way to add the US dead keys or any other solution. Thanks for your support.

Problem is solved. I missed in the keyboard layout the English fold-out menu and found there the VS International with dead keys. I added it and the keyboard is working properly now.